# What is this UI element called and how do I make it? (ios7)

Tags: ios, user-interface

The pop-up type thing (when you press the share button) shown in this picture: [image]

How can I make this in XCode?

EDIT: Sorry this wasn't clear, but I mean the actual container that appears when you press share, ignore the arrow

Comment: It's a `UIActivityViewController`.

Comment: If you found a solution to your problem, don't forget to select the appropriate one reply as the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The entire container for all of these buttons is a `UIPopoverController`, but that single button, or that type of popover, is the `UIActivityViewController`. You can show the default one, which is context aware, and you can also create your own `UIActivity` subclass to perform custom activities.

Answer (score 0):

It is UIPopoverController
[Reference](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CB4QFjAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.apple.com%2Flibrary%2Fios%2Fdocumentation%2Fuikit%2Freference%2FUIPopoverController_class%2FReference%2FReference.html&ei=ynG0U8HwM-jR7AbQ9YCgCQ&usg=AFQjCNG5OoSkJjrx_o8bSNqyOU-wszBoiA&sig2=SFa-0MrnjCCWYg6TzQnEBQ&bvm=bv.70138588,d.ZGU)